# Probabilistic hough transform openCV

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to obtain only vertical lines in the image using the probabilistic hough function. Right now I have it detecting lines perfectly, but I need to modify it to show only vertical lines. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

```
     HoughLinesP(edges, linesP, 1, CV_PI/180, 50, 50, 10 );
 printf("Probabilistic Hough found %ld lines\n",linesP.size());
 // Draw the lines extracted
 cvtColor(edges, coloredges, CV_GRAY2BGR);
vector<Vec2f> VlinesP;
 for( size_t i = 0; i < linesP.size(); i++ ) 
 {
   Vec4i l = linesP[i]; 
   line( coloredges, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0,0,255), 1, CV_AA);
 }
 imshow("Probabilistic Hough detected lines", coloredges);
 waitKey(0);

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calc angle in radians:

```
angle = math.atan2(l[1] - l[3], l[0] - l[2])
```

And filter lines with angle in area CV_PI / 2.